# Theorem about necessary conditions and sufficient conditions for optimality

Tags: optimization

I have problems understanding the following theorem.

[image]

I don't understand whether (a) is neccesary condtion, sufficient condition or both; or (b) is neccesary condtion, sufficient condition or both.

Hope someon can help